# Sites with overlapping code-bases. Developing multiple sites with little changes

Tags: web-development, php, programming-practices

I have to develop 3 different sites

1. video.com for hosting video
2. audio.com for hosting audio
3. docs.com for hosting docs.

*domain names for example only*

Almost 80% of the functionality is the same for all the three, with remaining 20% being completely different features...

How do I handle this? How does sites like SO handle this?

I am developing this in YII framework and was thinking of having these different features as modules but in this case the menu/code links in html code can become difficult.

Answer (score 2):

The way we've done it at companies I've worked at is that we have a common code line in source control. This is where that 80% of code lives. It is 100% functional and could be deployed on it's own if needed. It's like the vanilla website.

When a new website comes along that needs to build on this base, we branch the code from the common line into a new project. All customization are done in that branch with releases coming from there.

If a bug in the common code is discovered in a project, then it is fixed in the common line and then pushed to all the projects so that all projects get the fix. You never push from a project site down into common code, you always push from common code out to project sites.

As for skinning a site. Using CSS helps a lot. I follow Jeff Atwood's blog, Coding Horror, and he did a post that really helped us out. It was how I was introduced to less. It goes into how the Stack Exchange network is able to skin their sites quickly and easily.

[You can find the post here.](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/04/whats-wrong-with-css.html) I'm not sure if there is a way to use it in php, but it's something to look into. It has been a life saver for us at my current company.

Answer (score 0):

Drupal makes quick work on running multiple sites from a single codebase - http://drupal.org/node/43816

I do believe CodeIgniter also has a very good ability to build a cluster of sites using the same codebase - http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2009/06/How-to-Multi-site-CodeIgniter-Set-up

Answer (score 0):

- Extract as much business functionality as possible into separate common modules (in case of our asp.net applications we use separate projects within a solution for generic logic in an application and a separate common solution for core/helper modules used across a range of a applications),
- Do not hardcode, make things configurable either through some kind of config files or store configuration in a db. Use a separate config/db for each domain. This allows you to keep a single codebase and decide on deploy which 'flavour' of the application to use. This applies just as well to site-specific constants, db connection strings (those you obviously can't store in a db), css files to use and site content, including site navigation,
- Break down pages into components. Use user controls or whatever the equivalent in PHP may be (turns out it's not as simple as I thought, but you might want to check [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/960097/alternative-of-asp-nets-usercontrols-in-php)). You can assemble the components as needed and reuse them between sites,
- Use separate css files if there are vast differences in design of the sites, otherwise use the same css as a base and introduce site-specific styling using a top-level class (e.g. use `.btn` for base styling of buttons and `.audio-com .btn` or `.video-com .btn` for site specific styling). Using css preprocessors like LESS or SASS makes this approach feel natural. Tyanna provided a link to a blog post on the topic in an earlier answer,
- Avoid forking the codebase. If you can't, at least make sure you have a decent working codebase before you do so. If you're writing from scratch, finish one site as a prototype, and only then fork. Having to maintain and apply bug fixes to three separate codebases is a hassle, and will only get worse as your codebases diverge with time. In general, this is a decision you shouldn't take lightly, even if it will make your life simpler for the moment. It will come back to you if/when you'll be tasked with maintaining the sites.